# Train/Validate/Test in Scikit learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to x_train, X_validate, and y_test. This is the code I have so far, but I do not think it is right. Could someone please guide me? I typically only see train and test, not all 3 together.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.T, y.T, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
```

Comment: This isn't the place for coding questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above is on the right track, in the sense that `scikit-learn`'s `train_test_split` *does* only produce train and test sets for each of `X` and `y`.

To get the validation you're looking for, we'd often use cross-validation (whether manually or using a module like `GridSearchCV`) with `X_train` and `y_train` as inputs. Then we'd do final predictions for measuring test-set AUC or accuracy using `X_test` and `y_test`.

Comment: Would you mind typing the code out? I've never used train_test_split before. The instructions of the practice were to "do train/validate/test split"